# iOS 7.1 crash if heightForRowAtIndexPath is not declared

Tags: uitableview, ios7, autolayout, ios7.1

I was trying to use `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` for dynamic cell height with AutoLayout and working as expected in iOS8 but crush in iOS7.1 by saying this:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyProject.ViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79e91350'`

[image]

If I define `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, error go away but cell won't auto size itself. Any idea?

Update: It's indeed available in iOS 7.0, right?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try :

```
 if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 ){
    self.tableView.rowHeight =  UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 206;
}




 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {



        if NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 {              
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            } else {return 206}
    }
```

Comment: won't passing an explicit value in heightForRowAtIndexPath: be against the core idea of implementing the dynamic cell height concept ? I have a similar issue which I can not figure out - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425782/ios7-0-and-ios-7-1-doesnt-honor-dynamic-tableview-height?noredirect=1#comment47022763_29425782