# iOS 7.1 doesn't allow Dynamic tableview Height

Tags: uitableview, ios8, autolayout, ios7.1, ios-autolayout

I've a VC lets call it **"DetailsVC"** with a tableView which will have rows with different height.

The **"DetailsVC"** is added as Subview to another VC called **"MainVC"**

In **"DetailsVC"**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
    [self.tableView needsUpdateConstraints];

    CGFloat containerHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.bounds) + self.addressLabelHeightConstraint.constant;
    [self.tableViewdelegate punchDetailsController:self didUpdateTableViewWithHeight:containerHeight];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

This works well in iOS 8 and above and DOESN'T WORK in iOS 7 or 7.1

The tableview's height is coming out as ZERO and doens't display tableview at all.

I understand "UITableViewAutomaticDimension" is part of iOS 8 and not available in iOS 7.

What other approach should I use to work for both iOS 7 and iOS 8.

My issue is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425782/ios7-0-and-ios-7-1-doesnt-honor-dynamic-tableview-height

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll just have to check for OS version and for lower than 8, calculate the height of the cell manually and return it.
Also, for performance reasons, for iOS 7 return a constant, or just don't implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`

Z.