# systemLayoutSizeFittingSize not returning a size big enough for my UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitableview

I'm using a static Table View to show some data and since my data is dynamic, I need a Cell with can adjust its size according to its content. I have override the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 4 {
        let size = itemDescription.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
        return size.height
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

I have tried both `UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` and `UILayoutExpandedSize` and both will return a `CGSize` with 140 in height which is not enough to show my text.

I also tried to increase the number of lines in the `UILabel`, but it doesn't work either.

On storyboard, my Cell is a basic `TableViewCell`.

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use self-sizing cells you don't need to override `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Override `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and return either an estimate or `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. And, it's important, you have to have explicit constraints to all 4 sides of a cell. For `UILabel` specify 0 as numer of lines to enable text auto-height.

Comment: Drop an explicit height constraint on the view with 999 priority. If the cell would size correctly the problem is definitely in constraints.

Comment: Since I'm not using a Custom Cell, the `UITableViewCell` doesn't have any constraints.

Comment: check that `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` have no explicit heights specified anywhere in Interface Builder. comment out `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and leave only `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate methods.

Comment: It's working now! I had to set `tableView.rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` on code to make it work. Thank you for your Help @rshev

Comment: `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` crashes on iOS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958707/ios-7-1-crash-if-heightforrowatindexpath-is-not-declared